# Tricky pure geometry proof

Tags: geometry

In a triangle ABC median AD divides angle(BAC) such that

angle(BAD) : angle(CAD) = 2:1.

Then prove that:

$ \cos(A/3) = \sin B/(2\;\sin C) $

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\angle{BAD}=\alpha$ and $\angle{CAD}=\beta$. Then we are given that $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\frac{2}{1}$. Then $A=\alpha+\beta=3\beta$. Using sine rule in $\Delta ABD$ gives
$$\frac{\sin \alpha}{\sin B}=\frac{BD}{AD}.$$
Likewise in $\Delta DAC$ we get
$$\frac{\sin \beta}{\sin C}=\frac{DC}{AD}.$$
But $BD=DC$. Therefore
$$\frac{\sin \alpha}{\sin B}=\frac{\sin \beta}{\sin C}.$$
But $\alpha=2\beta$, so we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin 2\beta}{\sin B} & =\frac{\sin \beta}{\sin C}\\
\frac{2 \sin \beta \cos \beta}{\sin B} & =\frac{\sin \beta}{\sin C}\\
2 \cos \beta& =\frac{\sin B}{\sin C}
\end{align*}
Now use the fact that $\beta=\frac{A}{3}$.